# How to find th author of a message in discord, and how to use that to figure out if it has the right permissions for a command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out if the author a command, has the right permissions to carry out the command. But the console keeps saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'permission' of undefined`. Heres my code.

```
  name: 'mute',
  description: 'mutes someone',
  execute(message,args) { 
    const target = message.mentions.members.first();
    const muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'MUTED')
    let sender = message.author
    let role = message.member.roles

   if(!target || !message.user.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES') ) {
    message.channel.send("You cant mute that member.")
   } else if(message.sender.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {  
    target.roles.set([muteRole])    
    //target.roles.add(muteRole)
    message.channel.send("User has been muted")
  }
  }
}
```

I know that it can't find the author, but I don't know how to fix that. Also I think the `message.user.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES')` is also wrong, but again I don't know how to fix it. Online it has conflicting information.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting `Message.sender` from...

Comment: Yea this was really bad code lmao. I fixed it alr tho so its all good. Sry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'mute',
  description: 'mutes someone',
  execute(message,args) { 
    const target = message.mentions.members.first();
    const muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'MUTED')
    let user = message.author;

   if(!target || !message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
    message.channel.send("You cant mute that member.")
   } else if(message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {  
    target.roles.set([muteRole])    
    //target.roles.add(muteRole)
    message.channel.send("User has been muted")
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the message.user.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES') with:

```
message.member.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES')
```

This uses the GuildMember object instead of the User object because you can’t fetch roles from a User object.

Comment: it didn't work. it still gave me the same error

Comment: Try changing ```} else if(message.sender.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {``` to ```} else if(sender.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {``` and same with ```if(!target || !message.user.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES') ) {``` to ```if(!target || !sender.permission.has('MANAGE_ROLES') ) {```

Comment: There is no `user` and `sender` variables so these won't work.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros There is a let user = message.author

Comment: Ah, I see, completely missed that. The problem is `message.author` is still a `User` and `User`s don't have `permissions`, only `GuildMember`s have.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the answer to use a GuildMember class.

Comment: You're welcome. Now it only needs an extra `s`. It's [`premissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions).